# Decimal to binary conversion code giving some unusual data

Tags: c

Here is my code for the decimal to binary conversion program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void main()
{
    int q,r,bn[20],i=0,n;

    printf("enter the decimal integer:");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    while (q>0)
    {   
        q=n/2;
        r=n%2;
        bn[i]=0;
        bn[i]=r;
        n=q;
        i=i+1;
    }
    while(i>=0)
    {
        printf("%d ",bn[i]);
        i=i-1;
    }
}
```

Now the output is something like this:
enter the decimal integer:2
1628731552 1 0 
now i don't understand where this number 1628731552 came from ??

Any Help !!

Comment: `while (q>0)` -- `q` is uninitialized

Comment: `while (q>0)` causes undefined behaviour because you are reading an uninitialized value.

Comment: Why do you have `bn[i]=0;` when you use `bn[i]=r;` just after it?

Answer (score 1):

Your code invokes Undefined Behavior because of two reasons.

1. `q` isn't initialized when the execution of the program reaches

   ```
   while(q>0)
   ```
2. Secondly, you need to increment `i` when it is above 0:

   ```
   if(q>0)
       i=i+1;
   ```

   Otherwise, when you input 2, `i` will be 2 when the first `while` loop exits and your last `printf` will access `a[2]`(which is uninitialized) in the first iteration of the last `while` loop.

   Alternatively, you can use `i--` or `i=i-1;` between the two loops to solve this issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void main()
{
    int q,r,bn[20],i=0,n;

    printf("enter the decimal integer:");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    while (n>0) //fix
    {   
        q=n/2;
        r=n%2;
        //bn[i]=0;
        bn[i]=r;
        n=q;
        i=i+1;
    }
    i--;//go to last idx
    while(i>=0)
    {
        printf("%d",bn[i]);
        i=i-1;
    }
    printf("\n"); // end
}
```